# Progress bar not showing up till last moment

Tags: java, android

This is my first android app,
I am calling function `result` on button click but as its call to `findTimeTable` takes time i want to show a progress bar but for some reason progress bar fails to show up until last moment just before the dialog box is created which defeats my purpose of showing the progress bar for that time period. In-fact that last moment is only visible when i don't set their visibility back to what it was.

```
public void result(View view) throws IOException {
    findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.chooseFile).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    findViewById(R.id.chooseDay).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    findViewById(R.id.chooseTime).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    findViewById(R.id.findFaculty).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    String n = findTimetable(index_day, index_time);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("hello" +n);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i){
                }
            });
    final Dialog mDialog = builder.create();
    mDialog.show();
    findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    findViewById(R.id.chooseFile).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.chooseDay).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.chooseTime).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.findFaculty).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

I found a relevant answer [android progress bar not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44032096/android-progress-bar-not-showing)
but as i am not familiar with threads in programming i could not implement it properly on my code.
please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an AsyncTask for the heavy comupting and add the progress bar in its Pre/Post states, and if you choose to update the GUI from there you need to run that code on the UI Thread.

Example AsyncTask:

```
 private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
          // Start progressbar
      }

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
          // Computing goes here
          return null;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         // Stop progressbar
         UpdateMyGUI();
     }

     @Override
     protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
         // Update progressbar (?)
     }
}

private void updateMyGUI(){
    runOnUiThread (new Runnable() {  
        public void run() {
            // Update GUI Here.
        }
    });
}
```